# I'm using discord.py and my instant invite command isn't working

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I found this piece of code on another post that could generate an instant invite for the server, but it's not working for me! There are no shown errors or problems in the console either. Its just when I use the command, Discord does literally nothing!

Here is my code:

```
@client.command()
async def invite(ctx):
    link = await ctx.create_invite()
    await ctx.channel.send(link)
```

Any idea of what's happening?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify where you want to create this invite, the invite location if you will. The code below creates an invite in the current channel that lasts for 300 seconds.

```py
@client.command()
async def invite(ctx):
    link = await ctx.channel.create_invite(max_age = 300)
    await ctx.channel.send(link)
```

[Here is the link to the docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=invite#discord.abc.GuildChannel.create_invite) for further reference.

[image: Working command]

**P.S.**: When testing your code, I did receive an error `AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'create_invite'`. If you have an error handler, you may want to ask a separate question on how to make it better.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have the permission "Create Instant Invite" in the channel you using the command?

Comment: Probably, let me check... After all it is my server!

Comment: I in fact do have the permission! I'll check the bot's permission...